# Jest Not Using Mocked Version of Function

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am facing an interesting issue which I just can not figure out with Jest.

I have two very similar methods in which one mocks just fine and the other does not

**Method One:**

```
async create(payload: CreateCustomerDto): Promise<any> {
    const stripeCustomer: Stripe.Customer = await this.stripeService.createCustomer(
      payload,
    )

    return this.customersRepository.create(stripeCustomer)
  }
```

**Method Two**

```
async create(payload: CreateCardDto): Promise<any> {
    const stripeCard: Stripe.Card =
      await this.stripeService.createCreditCard(payload)

    return this.cardsRepository.create(stripeCard)
  }
```

When running my test suite for **Method One**, this one correctly mocks out the call to **Stripe** with the function

```
it('/POST', async () => {
      jest
        .spyOn(stripeService, 'createCustomer')
        .mockResolvedValue({ id: 'cus_I0OwQwoHWOAiwV' })

      const payload = {
        email: 'testing@test.com',
        metadata: {
          companyId: '1',
        },
      }

      const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post(`${apiPrefix}/customers`)
        .set('access-token', `${jwtToken}`)
        .send(payload)
        .then(({ body }) => body)

      expect(response.email).toEqual(payload.email)
      expect(response.stripeCustomerId).toEqual('cus_I0OwQwoHWOAiwV')
    })
```

However, when running my test suite for **Method Two**, this one is not using the mocked call to **Stripe** with the function even those it states it is mocked and tries to execute

```
    it.only('/POST creates new card', async () => {
      const { stripeCustomerId } = customers[0]

      jest
      .spyOn(stripeService, 'createCreditCard')
      .mockResolvedValue({ mocked: true })

      const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post(`${apiPrefix}/cards`)
        .set('access-token', `${jwtToken}`)
        .send({
          secretKey: 'fake_key',
          stripeCustomerId,
          tokenId: '1',
        })
        .then(({ body }) => body)

      console.log('stripeService', stripeService)
    })
```

Console log showing it is mocked

```
console.log
    stripeService StripeService {
      configService: ConfigService {
        internalConfig: {
          app: [Object],
          database: [Object],
          services: [Object],
          logger: [Object]
        },
        cache: {},
        _isCacheEnabled: false
      },
      createCreditCard: [Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
        getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    }
```

If I execute the function directly: `this.stripeService.createCreditCard()` then it will return the mocked value. Just not sure why it is not working when call inside its parent like the other test is.

Would anyone know why this may be happening? The code in test amongst these functions are almost identical so this is making no sense to me

Comment: what if you add `jest.clearAllMocks()` before anything? like inside some `beforeEach` hook

Comment: Make sure you attach a catch to your `createTestingModule` call. I have had some really puzzling issues similar to this only to discover that there were exceptions that jest was eating up and not telling me about. Alternatively, could you post the test file?